# Twitter Bootstrap. 3 Column with Header and Footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to work out how to make a very simple layout using Twitter bootstrap 3.

It is basically a sticky header (always at the top of the viewport), a footer that resides at the bottom of the content (not fixed to the bottom of the viewport) and then, between the two - 3 columns. The left and right ones are fixed width (200px) and the middle column is to be fluid dependant on the screen width.

I've tried way too many ways of doing this and I'm starting to lose the plot slightly.
Could someone please help me out.

EDIT 1(5): My header footer layout code. I've tried too many different things to try and achieve the three columns. Edit for another attempt. Issue here is that a) the columns are fluid and b) the 12 column layout is to the left and doesn't occupy the whole width.

```
    <div class="container-full">      
        <div class="navbar navbar-static-top">  
            <div class="navbar-inner blue-bg">
                <a href="#" class="brand"><img src="images/kab/logo-header.png" alt="KAB Logo Large"/></a>
            </div>
        </div>  

        <div class="container-full">    
            <div class="row-fluid">

                <div class="span1">
                    <h4>Left Column</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="span10">
                    <h4>Center Content</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="span1">
                    <h4>Right Column</h4>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom">
            <div class="navbar-inner blue-bg" style="height: 77px;"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

EDIT 2:  Added an awful attempt trying it with DIV's, but doesn't that defeat the object of using a framework?

EDIT 3: Structure of ideal layout

```
    +------------------------------------------------------+
    |                       Header                         |
    +------------+------------------------------+----------+
    |            |                              |          |
    |            |                              |          |
    |  Fixed     |       Fluid Column           |  Fixed   |
    |  200px     |                              |  200px   |
    |            |                              |          |
    |            |                              |          |
    |            |                              |          |
    |            |                              |          |
    |            |                              |          |
    +------------+------------------------------+----------+
    |                        Footer                        |
    +------------------------------------------------------+
```

EDIT 4: Here is a fiddle I found on here and have adapted it to suit however there is some whitespace on the right side. Also, is this the best practice when it comes to achieving this type of layout?

http://jsfiddle.net/FzVtx/123/

Comment: Can you show some code either here or in a fiddle?

Comment: @MF82 Here is a fiddle. I've tweaked one I found elsewhere however its not quite right and I'm not 100% sure if this is the right way to go about it. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/FzVtx/123/)

Comment: Nobody? I've still not sorted this - so simple and it's driving me round the bend!

Comment: You're talking about BT3, but "span1 or span10' are obsolete... You should use 'col- [xs-sm-md-lg] -1' . http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

Comment: This is the best I could find: http://www.bootply.com/9logoZy2fv

Answer (score 1):

If anybody still using BS3, and wants to know how to get this design, this is the solution:

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<style>
/* 
This for the 200px. 
Put as comments cause it's breaking the view to 3 nested divs on many small-screen divices.

.col-xs-2 {min-width: 200px;}
*/
</style>
<div class="container-fluid text-center">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">Header</div>
  </nav>
  <div class="row" style="margin-top: 50px;">  
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <h4>Left Column</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <h4>Center Content</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <h4>Right Column</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="container">Footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it with Bootstrap. But the normal way to do it will be this.

Have a header with width 100%;
Have three divs. Left div with width 200px and float left, right div with width 200px and float right. Both with display:block. And the middle div with display:inline-block;
Have a footer with width 100%;